# How to make instance of own payment gateway in NordPOS?

Tags: java

I need to initialize(bind name to appconfig), somewhere in [NordPOS](https://github.com/nordpos) project, my realizations of payment gateway. Can't find the right place.

NordPOS based on Openbravo, so i used this article as a guide:
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/OpenbravoPOS_Payment_Gateways#Developers_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the payment gateway in the configuration window. To open the configuration window you will have to execute a  configuration.bat(windows) or  configuration.sh(linux).

You might want to look at the link below for more details:

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects:POS/Installation#Payment

Comment: I need to put into "payment gateway" combobox selection my own realization(which i already created). I can add name, butt it should be defined to object of gateway class.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! 
In "nordpos-3.0.6CE\services\META-INF\services\com.nordpos.payment.gateway.PaymentGatewayInterface" 
append classpath to your implementation of PaymentGatewayInterface.

It will be used by ServiceLoader.